# using recursion to find the integer appearing odd times

Tags: python, recursion, range

I am looking for some guidance with the following code please. I am learning Python and I come from Java and C# where I was a beginner. I want to write a function which returns the number which appears an odd number of times. Assumption is that the array is always greater than 1 and there is always only one integer appearing an odd number of times. I want to use recursion.

The function does not return a value as when I store the result I get a NoneType. Please, I am not looking for a solution but some advice of where to look and how to think when debugging.

```
def find_it(seq):
    seqSort = seq
    seqSort.sort()
    def recurfinder(arg,start,end):
        seqSort = arg
        start = 0
        end = seqSort.length()-1
            for i in range(start,end):
                counter = 1
                pos = 0
            if seqSort[i+1] == seqSort[i]:
                counter+=1
                pos = counter -1
            else:
                if(counter % 2 == 0):
                    recurfinder(seqSort, pos+1, end)
                else:
                    return seqSort[i]
        return -1
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions. use version specific tags at your discretion. Note, generally, Python 3 is assumed, since Python 2 is rapidly approaching its end of life.

Comment: understood, apologies and thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call `recurFinder` from somewhere outside of `recurFinder` to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Using a dictionary would make this a lot simpler; faster, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getOddOccurrence(arr, arr_size): 

    for i in range(0, arr_size): 
        count = 0
        for j in range(0, arr_size): 
            if arr[i] == arr[j]: 
                count+= 1

        if (count % 2 != 0): 
            return arr[i] 

    return -1

arr = [2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2 ] 
n = len(arr) 
print(getOddOccurrence(arr, n))
```

Comment: Note that this implementation does `N²` steps for an array of size `N`. So while it's fine for small arrays, it will get slow rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses recursion and a `dict` for fast counter lookups -

```
def find_it(a = [], i = 0, d = {}):
  if i >= len(a):
    return [ n for (n, count) in d.items() if count % 2 == 1 ]
  else:
    d = d.copy()
    d[a[i]] = d.get(a[i], 0) + 1
    return find_it(a, i + 1, d)
```

It works like this -

```
print(find_it([ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5 ]))
# [ 1, 2, 4 ]

print(find_it([ 1, 2, 3 ]))
# [ 1, 2, 3 ]

print(find_it([ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ]))
# []

print(find_it([]))
# []
```

---

Above `i` and `d` are exposed at the call-site. Additionally, because we're relying on Python's default arguments, we have to call `d.copy()` to avoid mutating `d`. Using an inner `loop` mitigates both issues -

```
def find_it(a = []):
  def loop(i, d):
    if i >= len(a):
      return [ n for (n, count) in d.items() if count % 2 == 1 ]
    else:
      d = d.copy()
      d[a[i]] = d.get(a[i], 0) + 1
      return loop(i + 1, d)
  return loop(0, {})
```

It works the same as above.